# Capture httpWebrequest sent by the webbrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Actually am navigating to a url using the webBrowser Control in my c# project.Now i have to record the action performed by the user and replay it later.So i need to capture the request and response sent by the webBrowser Control to the server.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check what elements were actually clicked (ie. if they don't go to a new page), perhaps you could use some JavaScript injected by C# to keep a log in a hidden tag which you can then reference from C# to see what was done.

Comment: Thanks Drackir but the locationChanged event is not fired when i perform any action within that page or even if i move from one page to another.

Comment: locationChanged is not talking about URL, isn't it??? Looks like it is window location x,y not page change in webbrowser.

Comment: @masato-san: Oh wow. You're right. I assumed that location was referring to the URL, but it's the location of the control. Whoops!